# Color of headerBackTitle react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to set the color of the `headerBackTitle` in the `Stacknavigator`?

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    ...
    headerBackTitle: "Back",
    }),
    ...
```

Depending on the background color the header has, the `headerBackTitle` is not readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `headerBackTitleStyle` to style your back button.

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    ...
    headerBackTitle: "Back",
    headerBackTitleStyle: {
        color: 'pink'
    }
}),
...
```

Comment: +1 but the arrow still stays the same default color (blue in this case on iOS). any more hidden settings?

Comment: @Fakeer There is no other options as far as I know but if you are still having a problem try creating a new question with a [mcve]. You might be using it wrong.

Comment: @bennygenel: tried out your example: it does change the text of the back button, but the arrow is still default iOS blue

Answer (score 7):

I know this question was a long time ago but anyways, `headerBackTitleStyle` will change only the color, better use `headerTintColor: '#FF0000'` to change text and icon

Comment: 2021 - this should be the accepted answer!